# Call parent function passed as prop in React

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm creating a survey-type app in React.  The questions are arranged as items in a carousel.

When the user selects an answer - I AM able to change the state of the question (setting a button as active).  However, I would also like to advance the carousel to the next item.

```
var Question = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            selectedIndex: -1
        };
    },

    handleClick(index) {
        this.setState({selectedIndex: index});
        this.props.onQuestionAnswered();
    },

    render() {
        var answerItems = answerChoices.map(function (answer) {
            return (
                <ReactBootstrap.ListGroupItem
                    key={answer.text}
                    text={answer.text} 
                    active={answer.index == this.state.selectedIndex} 
                    onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, answer.index)}>
                    {answer.text}
                </ReactBootstrap.ListGroupItem>
                );
        }.bind(this));

        return (
            <div>
                <h3>{this.props.qText.text}</h3>
                <ReactBootstrap.ListGroup>
                    {answerItems}
                </ReactBootstrap.ListGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Carousel = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      index: 0,
    };
  },

  handleSelect() {
    this.setState({
      index: 1
    });
  },

    render() {

        var questionItems = questionContent.map(function (question) {
            return (
                <ReactBootstrap.CarouselItem key={question.text}>
                    <Question qText={question}/>
                </ReactBootstrap.CarouselItem>
                );
        });

        return (
            <ReactBootstrap.Carousel interval={false} activeIndex={this.state.index} onQuestionAnswered={this.handleSelect}>
                {questionItems}
            </ReactBootstrap.Carousel>
        );
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <h4>Survey</h4>
            <Carousel/>
        </div>
        );
    }
});


React.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('content'));
```

I have a full JSFiddle available: http://jsfiddle.net/adamfinley/d3hmw2dn/

Console says the following when I try to call the function prop:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onQuestionAnswered is not a function

**What do I have to do to call the parent function?  Alternatively - is there a better pattern I should be using? (first time with React).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the error is coming from the Question component, which doesn't have the `onQuestionAnswered` prop. So you simply need to pass it in your `questionItems` map iteration.

```
    var self = this;
    var questionItems = questionContent.map(function (question) {
        return (
            <ReactBootstrap.CarouselItem key={question.text}>
                <Question onQuestionAnswered={self.handleSelect} qText={question}/>
            </ReactBootstrap.CarouselItem>
            );
    });
```